Change the position plotly bar chart bars
Below is the code to re arrange a dynamic plotly-plot bar chart's bars on up and down button click, No ordering of  bars required, want to interchange the bars based on up down arrow click. Chart Legends are interchanging, but chart bars not shifting its position
Html
<div style="background-color: green; height: 20px">
  <button (click)="upBar()">Up</button>
  <button (click)="downBar()">down</button>
</div>

 <plotly-plot
        [divId]="graph.selectedGraph.name"
        [data]="graph.selectedGraph.data"
        [config]="graph.selectedGraph.config"
        [layout]="layout"
        (relayout)="draggedShape($event)"
        [ngClass]="{ 'single-data': graph.data && graph.data.length === 1 }"
        (legendClick)="launchColorPicker($event)"
      >
      </plotly-plot>

Typescript
barClickedEvent($event) {
        let graphData = [];
        let graphBarIndex = this.graph.data.findIndex((x) => x.name === $event.currentBarData.name);
        if (graphBarIndex !== -1 && graphBarIndex < this.graph.data.length - 1) {
          const foundItem = this.graph.data.splice(graphBarIndex, 1)[0]; // Remove the item from current index
          if ($event.barPosition === 'up') {
            graphBarIndex += 1;
            graphData = this.setGraphBar(graphBarIndex, foundItem);
          } else {
            graphBarIndex -= 1;
            graphData = this.setGraphBar(graphBarIndex, foundItem);
          }
          this.graph.data = [];
          this.graph.data = [...graphData];
        }
        console.log('barClickedEvent', $event);
      }


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working stackblitz where the issue happens!

@NarenMurali do you have any example for changing the position  plotly-plot bar chart bars based on some user inputs
